# How to use a MultiVariateNormal distribution in the latest version of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I need to use the `MultiVariateNormal` distribution from the `tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormal` However in the latest version of Tensorflow the above distribution is not available which leads to an error 
[image]

Can someone please point out which of the available distribution would take in mean and sigma and give the MultivariateNormal distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/MultivariateNormalFullCovariance)`defines the Multivariate Normal distribution that is parameterized by the`mean vector (mu)`and the`covariance matrix`.

An Example,

```
# Let mean vector and co-variance be:
mu = [1., 2] 
cov = [[ 1,  3/5],[ 3/5,  2]]

#Multivariate Normal distribution
gaussian = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(
           loc=mu,
           covariance_matrix=cov)

# Generate a mesh grid to plot the distributions
X, Y = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(-3, 3, 0.1), tf.range(-3, 3, 0.1))
idx = tf.concat([tf.reshape(X, [-1, 1]), tf.reshape(Y,[-1,1])], axis =1)
prob = tf.reshape(gaussian.prob(idx), tf.shape(X))

with tf.Session() as sess:
   p = sess.run(prob)
   m, c = sess.run([gaussian.mean(), gaussian.covariance()])
   # m is [1., 2.]
   # c is [[1, 0.6], [0.6, 2]]
```

[image]